# Override mail recipients for order state enter flow action and add data

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to add data for the mail that is sent via the flow action on `state_enter.*` events and override the recipients. But it doesn't seem to be possible by just listening to the `OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent` class since the dispatched event gets an explicit name.

So my desired solution doesn't work:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent::class => 'methodName'
    ];
}
```

As far as I know, I would need to create a listener for each state_enter event, which is a massive hustle and an issue if there are other states added afterward (eg. by store plugins).

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        'state_enter.order.state.cancelled' => 'methodName',
        'state_enter.order.state.completed' => 'methodName',
        'state_enter.order.state.in_progress' => 'methodName',
        'state_enter.order.state.open' => 'methodName',
        'state_enter.order.state.open_release' => 'methodName',
        'state_enter.order_delivery.state.cancelled' => 'methodName',
        ......
        ...
    ];
}
```

Is there a better way I might not know about?
So I basically want to override the recipients in the Event and add some additional data.

Listening to `state_machine.order.state_changed`, `state_machine.order_delivery.state_changed` and `state_machine.order_transaction.state_changed` doesn't work since the recipient and order data aren't forwarded to the `OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could listen to `FlowSendMailActionEvent` and change the recipients on the fly based on the prefix of the event name.

```php
class FlowSendMailActionEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            FlowSendMailActionEvent::class => 'onFlowSendMailAction',
        ];
    }

    public function onFlowSendMailAction(FlowSendMailActionEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!str_starts_with($event->getStorableFlow()->getName(), 'state_enter.')) {
            return;
        }

        $recipients = $event->getDataBag()->get('recipients');

        $recipients['john@example.com'] = 'John Doe';
        // ...

        $event->getDataBag()->set('recipients', $recipients);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works for overriding the recipients but not adding additional data to the template data (eg. extension to the order entity) the template is already rendered at that point, or am I wrong?

Comment: No the template is not yet rendered at that point. Check `$event->getStorableFlow()->data()` for the data available in the template.